# .htaccess to allow Facebook access to PHP files

Tags: facebook, .htaccess

I have a Facebook app running php scripts on my server in an iframe and would like to protect the PHP files from being accessed by anyone except for the Facebook app, so I used the following .htaccess:

```
<Files *.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
allow from facebook.com
</Files>
```

It doesn't work, I just get the message 'Forbidden You don't have permission to access /xxxxx/ on this server.' when I try to use my app inside Facebook.

What do I need to allow Facebook access to run the script in an iframe but block anyone else access?

Answer (score 0):

Check for the existence of `$_REQUEST['signed_request']`. Do something like

```
if( !isset($_REQUEST['signed_request']) )
  exit('Permission denied');
```

More info at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/